# NameError: global name 'sock' is not defined

Tags: python, scope, global, python-2.7

I've defined a socket called sock in my Main.py. From Main.py I import Functions.py, where there's a function (or a method, dunno how they're called in Python) called sendMessage. In sendMessage I need to use the sock I defined in my Main.py. How do I do this? I've tried adding `global sock` to my function/method, but to no effect.

### Main.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys 
import socket 
import string 
import os
import commands
import time
from config import *
from functies import *
from php import *

sock = socket.socket ()
sock.connect ((config['server']['host'], config['server']['poort']))

...
```

### Functions.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def sendMessage (receiver, message):
    global sock
    sock.send ('PRIVMSG ' + ontvanger + ' :' + message + '\n')
```

### The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 68, in <module>
    sendMessage (receiver, config['nick'] + ' is here!')
  File "/home/robin/microPy/Functions.py", line 4, in sendMessage
    sock.send ('PRIVMSG ' + receiver + ' :' + message + '\n')
NameError: global name 'sock' is not defined
```

Comment: (1) That's an odd choice of heading for Functions.py (b) You have not defined the global name sock. You are clearly aware of the import keyword, so why don't you use it?

Comment: @wim Typo xD I'm used to typing `.php`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no php-style module-overarching global variables in Python. Instead, let `sendMessage` take the socket as an argument, like this:

```
# main.py
import socket
from functions import *

sock = socket.socket ()
sock.connect ((config['server']['host'], config['server']['poort']))
sendMessage (sock, receiver, config['nick'] + ' is here!')
```

```
# functions.py ; not .php
def sendMessage(sock, receiver, message):
    sock.send ('PRIVMSG ' + ontvanger + ' :' + message + '\n')
```

Comment: Hmm... That's quite... limited. The code's going to be a mess in no time if I have to pass around each variable I need every time :(
Oh well, thanks :)

Comment: On the contrary, the [code's going to be a mess if you use global variables](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/37249/the-singleton-pattern). For example, how would you extend your program to use multiple sockets? If you really need a global variable, you can make a module `myGlobal` and assign it there.

Answer (score 2):

Your `functions.py` have no idea what `sock` is. Try passing sock instance as an argument.

```
def sendMessage (sock, receiver, message):
    sock.send ('PRIVMSG ' + ontvanger + ' :' + message + '\n')
```